# What is the SPWeb.Name property for?

Tags: development, spweb

I'm wondering what use does the SPWeb.Name property have. Is it displayed anywhere?

Comment: With the analysis feature of Reflector you'll find quite a few uses.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this may not be a definitive list but I can tell you it is definitly used in:

The list of Sites on the `/_layouts/mngsubwebs.aspx` page (Site Settings >> Sites and Workspaces)

The site settings title and description page `/_layouts/prjsetng.aspx` (Site Settings >> Title, Description and Icon) - In particular it is used when modifying and creating sub web's

It is also used in search alerts too - it is more like the URL name of the site rather than the textual display name of the site, so for example you can have a `SPWeb.Title` of "My New Site" but the URL will be `http://mydomainfoo.com/mynewsite` : the `SPWeb.Name` in this instance is "mynewsite"

Hope this helps

Stuart

Comment: So it can be seen as a kind of internal name?

Comment: Yes exactly, but with the additional use of being the name that is used in the URL.